# comparar desde una lista en python

Tags: python

tengo una lista la cual guarda saludos

```
saludo = ['bien', 'genial']
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que dependiendo la respuesta me de un argumento, ejemplo:

```
if saludo[] == 'bien':
print('Me alegro')
else:
print('Que bueno que estes genial')
```

El problema surge que no me da ningún resultado. Que estoy haciendo mal? Espero me ayuden, gracias!

Comment: creo que en python es necesario indentar el codigo

Comment: Además de lo que comenta Daniel, `if saludo[] == 'bien':` no es una sintaxis válida, falta especificar un índice, p.e  `if saludo[0] == 'bien':`. Por favor, muestra un [mcve] para que podamos comprender y reproducir el problema y poder ayudarte.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices FJSevilla, la varialble seria saludo, si pongo un 0, se que me va a decir "me alegro", pero queria hacer algo como un array en el cual lea las posibles respuestas ya que ahora le pongo "bien", pero puedo decirlo "mal" y tendria que buscar dentro de la lista esta "mal", espero haber sido claro... je

Comment: Seva, si lo que quieres es que en función de la cadena almacenada en una variable te imprima una respuesta acorde a ella (sin usar una estructura if-else), usa un diccionario y no una lista. La clave sería la cadena  y el valor su respuesta `{'bien': 'Me alegro', 'genial': 'Que bueno que estes genial'}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si, por lo que he entendido en tu comentario, lo que quieres es buscar si la palabra está en la lista, puedes simplemente utilizar `in`:

```
if 'bien' in saludo:
    print('Me alegro')
else:
    print('Que bueno que estes genial')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Cristian. No sabia utilizar `in`. Me sirvió para seguir aprendiendo. Gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te sirviera. Para lo que necesitabas pensé que era la mejor solución ya que con el `for` van a salir tantos mensajes como elementos tenga tu lista.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas comparar un elemento del array puedes realizarlo indicando su indice, recuerda que inicia con 0, por ejemplo, para comparar el primer elemento del array:

```
saludo = ['bien', 'genial']

#primer elemento del array, indice 0.
if saludo[0] == 'bien': 
    print('Me alegro')
else:
    print('Que bueno que estes genial')
```

Para realizar una comparación con todos los elementos del array, obtén los elementos del array mediante un `for` y realiza la comparación, recuerda que es importante la indentación :

```
saludo = ['bien', 'genial']
for i in range(len(saludo)):
    if saludo[i] == 'bien':
        print('Me alegro')
    else:
        print('Que bueno que estes genial')
```

tendrías como salida:

```
Me alegro
Que bueno que estes genial
```

aquí una [demo en linea](https://www.ideone.com/5dAikY).

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys... justo le respondi a Cristian. Vi que usaste `in`... gracias